# Modify a XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, celementtree

```
<grandParent>
    <parent>
       <child>Sam/Astronaut</child>
    </parent>
</grandParent>
```

I want to modify the above XML by adding another child tag inside parent tag. I'm doing something like this..

```
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
a=ET.Element('parent')
b=ET.SubElement(a,"child")
b.text="Jay/Doctor"
tree.write("test.xml")
```

Is this the correct way of modifying the xml file? Any better way? or what else should I be taking care of in the above code?

Comment: Did you run that code? What were the results?

Comment: When I run this code now, I don't see the XML getting modified. I thought I did see it getting modified earlier and I had received the results required but thought its not correct way hence posted.

Comment: When you ask questions on SO, it is good to include all the relevant information, including the expected and observed results of whatever code you post. Otherwise, good question.

Comment: Alright captain! Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code creates a whole new tree and adds Jay to it. You need to connect Jay to the existing tree, not to a new one.

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
a = tree.find('parent')          # Get parent node from EXISTING tree
b = ET.SubElement(a,"child")
b.text = "Jay/Doctor"
tree.write("test.xml")
```

If you want to search for a particular child, you could do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
a = tree.find('parent')
for b in a.findall('child'):
    if b.text.strip() == 'Jay/Doctor':
        break
else:
    ET.SubElement(a,"child").text="Jay/Doctor"
tree.write("test.xml")
```

Notice `a.findall()` (similar to `a.find()`, but returns all of the named elements). `xml.etree` has *very* limited search criteria. You might consider using `lxml.etree` and its `.xpath()` method.

Comment: thanks this works.I think I could use find() to verify no child similar to one I am about to enter exists. To avoid duplicates.

Comment: actually, how do I execute the find command inside the parent tag? Two parent tags could have same children but a single parent should not have duplicates..

Comment: that worked for me. This might be all I need from ElementTree. I will look into lxml.etree if I need more capability I guess. Thanks much!

Comment: Well I guess I spoke too soon - I am now having name spaces in the parent tag and my find all method now has a problem ...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'
How do I handle this?

Comment: I am doing something like this. 
spaces={'xmlns':'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0', 'xsi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'schemaLocation':'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'}
using spaces in the find all method.. find all('module', namespaces=spaces)

Comment: That sounds like a new question.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070180/working-with-namespace-while-parsing-xml-using-elementtree