# Working with namespace while parsing XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, celementtree

This is follow on question for [Modify a XML using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068629/modify-a-xml-using-elementtree)

I am now having namespaces in my XML and tried understanding the answer at [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree) and have the following.

XML file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <grandParent>
  <parent>
   <child>Sam/Astronaut</child>
  </parent>
 </grandParent>
</project>
```

My python code after looking at [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

spaces='xmlns':'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0','schemaLocation':'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'}

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
a=tree.find('parent')          
for b in a.findall('child', namespaces=spaces):
 if b.text.strip()=='Jay/Doctor':
    print "child exists"
    break
else:
    ET.SubElement(a,'child').text="Jay/Doctor"

tree.write("test.xml")
```

I get the error:
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: Neither of the code snippets you posted is valid Python. There's stray bits of XML in the first, messed up indentation in both, and missing brackets in the second.

Comment: Yes my bad. I tried to correct it now.

Comment: Aside: the indentation of `else` is incorrect. It wants to line up with `for`, not with `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems on this line:

```
a=tree.find('parent')
```

First, `<parent>` is not an immediate child of the root element. `<parent>` is a grandchild of the root element. The path to parent looks like `/project/grandparent/parent`. To search for `<parent>`, try the XPath expression `*/parent` or possiblly `//parent`.

Second, `<parent>` exists in the default namespace, so you won't be able to `.find()` it with just its simple name. You'll need to add the namespace.

Here are two equally valid calls to `tree.find()`, each of which should find the `<parent>` node:

```
a=tree.find('*/{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}parent')
a=tree.find('*/xmlns:parent', namespaces=spaces)
```

Next, the call to `findall()` needs a namespace qualifier:

```
for b in a.findall('xmlns:child', namespaces=spaces)
```

Fourth, the call to create the new child element needs a namespace qualifier. There may be a way to use the shortcut name, but I couldn't find it. I had to use the long form of the name.

```
ET.SubElement(a,'{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}child').text="Jay/Doctor"
```

Finally, your XML output will look ugly unless you provide a default namespace:

```
tree.write('test.xml', default_namespace=spaces['xmlns'])
```

Unrelated to the XML aspects, you copied my answer from the previous question incorrectly. The `else` lines up with the `for`, not with the `if`:

```
for ...
  if ...
else ...
```

Comment: I don't mind removing the project tag and add the name space to grandParent tag.
    <grandParent xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd>
    <parent>
    <child>Sam/Astronaut</child>
    </parent>
    </grandParent>

Comment: Works. You saved my day. Working with namespaces was difficult. BTW How do I add a new line character after the sub element has been written/added?

Comment: `newkid=ET.SubElement(...) ; newkid.text="Jay/Dr" ; newkid.tail="\n"`

Comment: tree.write('test.xml', default_namespace=spaces['xmlns'])
what if I can't provide default_namespace argument? any other way to make sure it isn't ugly?

Comment: It won't be terribly ugly. No, I don't know of any other way.

Comment: Add this anywhere before `tree.write()`: `ET.register_namespace('', 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58458/discussion-between-user2812714-and-rob).